# How can i include codeigniter views in a WP theme

Tags: codeigniter

So i have almost working CI +WP.

In my CI views i am able to put some basic WP functions. But the link to the actual post goes
to the WP folder. Here i would like to recreate the website look and feel.

So i was wondering how i could load->view header, footer etc from CI in WP

Answer (score 0):

Be careful doing this.  As the link points out... this is a good way to create unstable software.

Why are you mixing these things and for what purpose?  To create a plugin for WP or something similar?  It sounds like you are using it with themeing?

Answer (score -1):

I'd start by taking a look at [Dipping Into CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/dip_into_CI/)

Comment: I don't mind the down vote if you give a reason. Using Dipping into CodeIgniter does exactly what you are asking, but giving you access to the CodeIgniter super object. 

That will allow you to use `$this->load->view('whatever')`

Comment: hi zack, i didn't give you a down vote. tx for your reply i a going to take a look